# Search by type posts and taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, search, pre-get-posts

I want that my search page give results of posts (that i want that show) and taxonomy

The code to get just two type of posts:

```
function searchfilter($query) {

      if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
          $query->set('post_type',array('lesson','series'));
      }
 return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

I want it to look for taxonomy too
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom `tax_query` to your filter, and pass the search query to it:

```
function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $s = $query->get( 's' );
        $query->set('post_type', [ 'lesson', 'series' ] );
        $query->set( 
            'tax_query', 
            [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy', 
                    'field'    => 'name', 
                    'terms'    => $s ,
                ] 
            ] 
        );
    }
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: I edited your answer. Try that out.

Comment: what this query will do?

Comment: it will fetch the posts matches with search criteria and with taxonomy same as search keyword so most of the time you will get empty array even you have search results.